# existence of $T^k=0$ in a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm struggling with this question for some time. I would appreciate if you'd check what I did and correct me if I'm wrong:

I am requested to check whether this claim is correct or wrong:

> Let ${v_1,...,v_n}$ is a basis of $V$ and $T:V→V$ satisfies: $T{v_1}=0$, $T{v_i}=v_{i−1} (2\leq i\leq n)$, then there exists $T^k=0$ for some $1\leq k<n.$

What I did:

Because of $T^k$, I was quite sure that this question is about nilpotent matrix. However, in a nilpotent matrix the only eigenvalue should be $0$, and the minimal polynomial should be $T^k$ where $k \leq n$(because we're speaking of a linear transformation) . Basically, from what I understand, the transformation moves the main diagonal to the left, making it the trace. Because it's linearly independent, $\sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_k v_k \neq 0$, which means that the minimal polynomial is $k=n-1$, which makes it a true claim.

Am I correct? If not please correct me so I can learn and improve.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that $k<n$? What happens to $v_i$ after applying $T$ $j$ times? Moreover, why should your minimal polynomial be constant?

Comment: You're right that it's about a nilpotent matrix - but some of the things you're saying are a little unclear. Why does the question say $k<n$ and you say $k\leq n$? (There's a subtle but important point there.) Also, the minimal polynomial should be a polynomial in $T$, and $k = n-1$ doesn't make sense as a minimal polynomial: what do you mean by that?

Comment: by rereading your comments, i understand the mistakes i've done and the difference in this case between $k < n$(Whch is what i should've written) and $k \leq n$ which is incorrect, because k should be less than n, not equal to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When given a question like this, you can always perform a quick sanity check. Let's take $V$ to be $2$-dimensional, generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then:

$T^0(v_1) = v_1, T^0(v_2) = v_2$

$T^1(v_1) = 0, T^1(v_2) = v_1$

$T^2(v_1) = 0, T^2(v_2) = 0$

Does this satisfy the statement in the question or not? (If so, what is $k$? If not, why not?)

Comment: k seems to be n-1, and it does satisfy the requiremens

Comment: so this claim is true from what i understand thanks to what you've written and the comments above

Comment: Really? I disagree. What is n here, and what is k?

Comment: then i really don't understand @Billy. if $$T^2(\sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_k v_k)$ then it should be equal to:$\sum_{k=3}^n \gamma_k v_{k-2}$ which means that $T^m(\sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_k v_k)$ is equal to $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \gamma_k v_{k-m}$, knowing that $\sum_{k=1}^n \gamma_k v_k \ne 0$ because it is linearily independent.

what did i do wrong then?

Comment: I don't think I understand your complaint. You should be able to read off the values of n (the dimension of the vector space) and k (the nilpotency index of T) in my example above: if I'm not mistaken, we have $k = n = 2$. But this doesn't satisfy the hypothesis $``k<n"$ that the question asks for.

Comment: wasn't a complaint, tried to see what i'm doing wrong so i could do better

Comment: I wasn't criticising you. I just didn't understand the nature of your objection.